# python request/response without any framework

Tags: python, apache

I need to design a API where a request is made  to the URL and in turn return a response.
Now i do not want to use any framework as such.

So my question is how can i make this happen.I want to send a request from the web browser and get the response.I have the apache server setup.So where should my python code leave to receive the request and how to respond back

EDIT

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost/')
request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response.info().gettype()
```

Comment: Why can you not use any framework? Maybe homework?

Comment: Maybe use CGI scripts or mod_python?

Comment: Its not an homework.So i need to test the same on a local system and then a remote system.So setting up the frame work is a lot of work

Comment: What is the problem then? Are you making a proxy-like service?

Comment: @MartijnPieters:I was looking at the site you mentioned.Yes i was trying something like a web request is  made to a system which only responds with the response.so to simulate this on a local system i had mentioned to make a call from web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Flask, it's a microframework and setting it up should be a one-liner.

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Here're the docs for configuring Apache to run it:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

I know you said no frameworks, but this is a lot more simple than doing it yourself.

Comment: Can we do this using Urllib2 please see my edit

Comment: urllib2 is for making requests, not receiving them

Comment: yes but you can see the response of the request

Comment: Your original question said you want to send a request from the browser and receive it with python. Urllib2 doesn't provide a way to receive that request.

Comment: k i am using flask as u suggested.Its easy to install .Just one question how can i send a reponse with a dictionary

Comment: @app.route("/")
def hello():
   a= {'a':1,'b':2}
   return "hello world" + str(a) but return jsonify(a) doesnt work,i get an internal server error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16772/discussion-between-rajeev-and-tony-blundell)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that at the moment. If you're getting a specific error message, post a question with code snippets and the error codes.